# How to parse a filename in php and rename with a certain name

Tags: php

I have numerous .xlsx files looking like this "Export_buget_113880_vers20_16-04-2020.xlsx". I want to write a php script and run it over all these files and in the end the script should rename all files to just the big number.xlsx (e.g 113880.xlsx). How can i do that so i dont have to manually rename them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple using a regular expression.

Let's say you have a directory like

```
- test
    Export_buget_113880_vers20_16-04-2020.xlsx
    Export_buget_113881_vers20_16-04-2020.xlsx
    Export_buget_113882_vers20_16-04-2020.xlsx
```

then you can use glob to find all *.xlsx files in there.

```php
foreach(glob('./files/*.xlsx') as $filename) {
    $short = preg_replace('/.*_(\d+)_.*/', './files/$1.xlsx', $filename );
    if(!empty($short) && $short !== $filename) rename($filename, $short);
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working. Stored files in a folder called 'Bugete'. I also saved the script inside this folder and am running it like this "php script.php"(i might not be running ti correctly). I also did "chmod +x script.php" even tho i dont think this was necessary.

Comment: I've tested it locally. See that you need to adapt the path in the replacement, too.

Comment: I did too. I found the mistake. I delete "./files/" instead of "/files" and let the dot there. Works great. Thanks a lot!!!